# How to make sharing to LinkedIn work on IOS phone?

Tags: ios, iphone, linkedin-api, share

**Is anyone know how to let the image show out on IOS phone when sharing through LinkedIn mobile app?**

Currently I am using this 2 urls to share a post to linkedin.

```
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle/?mini=true&url=www.google.com

https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=www.google.com
```

For Andriod phone, it is automatically redirect to LinkedIn mobile app and show the image as shown in the below.

[image: LinkedIn Post]

But for IOS phone, it will redirect to the LinkedIn web and when click the '**open**' button to open in LinkedIn mobile app, the image will not show out.

[image: LinkedIn Web]